# Podio PHP API > Get item revision difference

Tags: php, api, podio

Hello im using https://github.com/podio/podio-php for communicate with Podio API and problem is that https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-revision-difference-22374 doesnt work...dunno why...

My code:

```
$client_id = "xxx";
$client_secret = "xxx";
$app_id = "xxx";
$app_token = "xxx";

Podio::setup($client_id, $client_secret);

try {
  Podio::authenticate_with_app($app_id, $app_token);
  $item_id = "xxx";
  $revision_from_id = 0;
  $revision_to_id = 1;
  $showDiff = PodioItemDiff::get_for( $item_id, $revision_from_id, $revision_to_id );

  echo $showDiff;

}
catch (PodioError $e) {
  // Something went wrong. Examine $e->body['error_description'] for a description of the error.
}
```

Result on page:

**Array**

can someone help me please?

Comment: My item has 17 revisions

Answer (score 0):

```
echo var_dump($showDiff);
```

problem fixed